# Design patterns, how do they differ from other programming styles?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Design patterns aren't necessarily a programming style but rather a template for solving a problem in a number of different situations.

But how do they differ from other programming styles?

Thanks

**Edit:**
"(a) What are design patterns? How do these differ from other programming styles? [7]"

Comment: Design patterns are not a programming style (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_style), as you said yourself, and trying to compare it as such is like comparing cars to elephants - can be done, but I don't see the point.

Comment: Yeah i agree i thought i was missing something, its basically an exam question which had me a bit stumped. Thats the reason i posted anyway. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: Without to know what do you mean with "other programming styles" it is rather hard to answer this question.

Comment: Thats just the question, the other part is what is a design pattern which follows on with how do these differ from other programming styles.

Comment: Could you post the verbatim text of the question?  As it is, this just doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A design pattern provides a known solution to a common design problem, and is given a name to allow programmers to communicate more efficiently.

However, I have no idea what you mean by "programming styles".

**Edit:** I think the question is simply very badly worded. While "design pattern" has a relatively clear definition, "programming style" is, in my experience, not a term with a generally agreed clear definition.  The question seems to assume that design patterns are a kind of programming style, and I don't think that's true.

Comment: +1 design patterns give developers a common language with which to talk about designs.

Comment: I agree, thats why i was a bit confused with what exactly its looking for. I think Dur4ndal(4th response) provides a reasonable foundation to answer this question. I'm assuming thats what the examiner is looking for anyway.
Thanks for taking time to respond.

Answer (score 1):

If we take "programming style" to mean [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_style), then the primary difference between programming styles and design patterns boils down to form vs. function: programming styles merely suggest how code is supposed to look, but dont have anything to say about how the code works; while design patterns are all about how code is programmatically structured and executes, but say nothing about how the code looks.

Comment: thats pretty good and i think it would make sense in the context of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Design patterns are common solutions to object-oriented programming problems, so they differ from other styles in exactly the same way that object-oriented programming does.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, programming styles refer to the "specifc" way in which you'd go about implementing something (Design patterns included). Although Design Patterns have traditionally been linked to OOP many design patterns still exist in other programming paradigms. The question, i think, is trying to prove whether or not you've got the difference between a "generic" and proven way of solving a problem, and an specific way of implementing a solution to "that" problem.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I agree with other answers and in additional to that I think some program specific properties integrated some design pattern philosophy. Like the "delegate" keyword in C#, which implements the delegate pattern but it is absolutely supported by the language itself.